# using $_POST["username"] in cUrl url

Tags: php, curl

I have a page with the basic form:

```
<form action="r.php" method="post">
    <span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Notch" id="minime_url_textbox" name="u">
    <label class="btn1 btn2 btn-2 btn-2g"> <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Resolve"> </label>
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    </span>
    </form>
```

when they type a username in the input box press enter they redirect to a r.php which has a include()'d php file containing:

```
<?php
//Urls to scrape from.
$user = isset($_GET['u']) ? $_GET['u'] : 'safetrbgds';

$URLs = array();
$URLs[] = 'http://namemc.com/u/'.$user;
$working = '';

//Curl scraper.
foreach($URLs as $URL){
    $ch     = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $page = curl_exec($ch);
    $text = strip_tags($page);
    $accounts = array();
    preg_match_all('/(\w+) \s+ is \s+ available/x',$text,$accounts);
    foreach($accounts[0] as $account){
        $working .= ''.$account.''. PHP_EOL . '';
    }
}

//Put the scraped proxies into the new .txt file.
file_put_contents('accounts.txt', $working, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

It does work with the  $user = isset($_GET['u']) ? $_GET['u'] : 'safetrbgds';
for the safetrbgds but not for ones the user actually styped in.

I tried:

```
$URLs[] = 'http://namemc.com/u/{$_POST["username"];}';
```

I simply need it to end up rendering for example:
$URLs[] = 'http://namemc.com/u/test';

Comment: PS I DO NOT want the url to be http://namemc.com/u/user=test I MUST get it as http://namemc.com/u/test

Comment: You use POST method but in r.php you try to get $_GET['u'].

Change 3 line to this:

$user = isset($_POST['u']) ? $_POST['u'] : 'safetrbgds';

Comment: Forgot to mention r.php isnt directly containing the PHP. Its on the page by doing Include() so im guessing you mean the php.php file.

Comment: Still doesnt work anyway

Comment: I think `$accounts[0]` should be `$accounts[1]` in the `foreach`.

Comment: That definitely isnt the problem and has nothign to do with my problem [0] is basically the first account. And my problem is getting users form inputted username to go into the url and not in an url like http://example.com/index.php?thing=123 i need it in the format http://example.com/UserInputtedUsernameHere

Comment: @pr0metheus is right, you have to use `$_POST`, or change the form to use `method="get"`. And in case the user adds spaces around the name, use `trim($user)`.

Comment: ive already tried that :(

Comment: you must debug your data. try after `preg_match_all` use `var_dump($accounts);`  to see what you extract and see if success

Comment: array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  [1]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
Thats what outputted no clue what it means

Comment: it means that your regular expression is wrong and you can't extract that what you excpet, so the foreach loop is pointless. ok try now before preg_match_all use `echo $test;` to see what content we try do retrive

Comment: dude im telling you right now the only problem in my script is just getting the link thing to work cause right now thats all thats not working if i were to replace the link with a normal one like namemc.com/u/Test it will work correct so please

Comment: ok try to top of script -> `var_dump($_POST);` to see what data we send to php

Comment: put that at the top of the php?

Comment: array(2) {
  ["u"]=>
  string(10) "sfdgdsgsdg"
  ["submit"]=>
  string(7) "Resolve"
}

Comment: Working there I guess but its not going onto the url properly

Comment: You see you get your data right. below as answer i write you code that working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
//Urls to scrape from.
$user = isset($_POST['u']) ? $_POST['u'] : 'safetrbgds';

$URL = 'http://namemc.com/u/'.$user;
$working = '';

    $ch     = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $page = curl_exec($ch);
    $text = strip_tags($page);
    $accounts = array();
    preg_match_all('/(\w+) \s+ is \s+ available/x',$text,$accounts);
    foreach($accounts[0] as $account){
        $working .= ''.$account.''. PHP_EOL . '';
    }


//Put the scraped proxies into the new .txt file.
file_put_contents('accounts.txt', $working, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Try this.

Here is solution with all data that you need.

```
<?php
//Urls to scrape from.
$user = isset($_POST['u']) ? $_POST['u'] : 'safetrbgds';
$URL = 'http://namemc.com/u/'.$user;
$ch     = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
$accounts = array();
preg_match_all('/<div class="alert alert-.*" role="alert">(.*)<\/div>/',$page,$accounts);
$data = !empty($accounts[0][0]) ? $accounts[0][0] : false;
$data = strip_tags($data, '<p></p>');
$data = str_replace('To visit Mojang and grab this name, click here.', '', $data);
$data = str_replace('<p style="margin-top: 0.5em">Want this name? Worried someone else will get it first? Snipe it with www.mcsniper.com! (Advertisement)</p>','',$data);
$data = str_replace('<p>', '',$data);
$data = str_replace('</p>', '',$data);
$data = $data.PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents('accounts.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Output accounts.txt

```
testsettestest is available! 
admin is unavailable!
Shieldon has been available since 2015-05-12 20:43:41+00. 
Zoroark will become available at 2015-06-11 18:53:57+00.
```

Comment: Worked amazing! Can I ask doe how can I get it to search for multiple preg_match_alls?

Comment: you mean, that you can check multiple users? for example you paste username line by line in textarea and than you check??

Comment: No no, Like get it to search for multiple preg_match_alls cause the page namemc has 3 things that mean an account is available, Avalaible in xx hours, Available since xxx I need to preg match all fo them so that it can definitely be sure its available for the checker. so I just need to add more than 1 preg_match_all that will output to the txt using file_put_contents

Comment: i can't see that information you talking about. only got `namnenvincve is available! To visit Mojang and grab this name, click here.`. Give me username that show us all information you need and i will extract for you.

Comment: https://namemc.com/u/Zoroark will become available at ... & https://namemc.com/u/Shieldon has been available since .... see. I also want to add one if its already taken.

Comment: check my new solution

Comment: Awesome dude thx! Final request is made in a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30423702/php-count-lines-containing-specified-string